# Horizontal Scroll and Content Cut Issue in Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, scrollbar

Description:
I have developed an interactive rating component , and it works well on various screen sizes except for when the width hits 400px. At that point, a horizontal scrollbar appears, and the content starts to get cut off. I've hosted the code on GitHub, and you can find it here.[link to repository](https://github.com/AnoshaSohail/interactive-rating-component-main.git)

Issue:

Horizontal scrollbar appears when the width is 400px or smaller.
Content gets cut off at the same width.

Request:
I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve the horizontal scrollbar and content cut-off issues for the responsive design of my interactive rating component. Plus, I find it challenging to make websites fully responsive, and I'm seeking best practices and tips to improve the overall responsiveness of my components and projects.

Any assistance or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please confine your question to one specific problem and put the code which demonstrates that problem into your question not in an external site.I

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using width with percentage that is not better solution, you should use width 100% with max-width px or rem unit and use media query too

for example

```
.container {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 450px;
   margin: 0 auto; // for center box if you want
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
   .container {
      max-width: 320px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I download the zip from the Github link you provided and when I extracted it and ran index.html the scrollbar worked fine no matter the resolution of the browser so the 400px thing sounds like a lie to me either that or you meant something else entirely and so you should word it differently also here is a link of me trying what you said wouldn't work: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6loM67gJfgGgsNKxn2Y8iUePQQ9H7-k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NSDoPR6WTlPdeFQkmo6IhzlhhnAs19fz/view?usp=drive_link  look at this ..as soon as hit 400px or smaller width this scroll bar appears and the content started to cut

Comment: sorry but the url you sent is private